error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/create-next-app.: Not found
error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/create-next-app.: Not found
Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has disabled PSReadLine for compatibility purposes. If you want to re-enable it, run 'Import-Module PSReadLine'.
PS C:\Users\Romil Sharma\zvscode> yarn create next-app.
yarn create v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/create-next-app.: Not found
    at params.callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\Romil Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:66680:18)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\Romil Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:141410:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Romil Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:142382:10)
    at Request.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Romil Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:142304:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Users\Romil Sharma\zvscode> 


Remove the . from the end of your command, it should just be yarn create next-app
